# Are there any mostly-passive funds that become active after stock market crashes?

Tags: etf, index-fund, market-indexes, recession

I am thinking of the following scenario:

1. Expansion, index with low fees
2. After a market crash, lever up and buys equities

Does there exist a fund which follows this strategy? Preferably an ETF?

Comment: Which country you are referring to ?

Comment: What is a  mostly-passive fund that becomes active after a stock market crash?  Got an example?  Or is this something that you hope exists?

Comment: @BobBaerker This is something the OP hopes exists.

Comment: @riya United States

Answer (score 2):

Something close to what you're looking for would be a balanced/tactical allocation fund, like VBIAX. It invests in a fixed mix of 60% stocks, 40% bonds.

When the market crashes, to rebalance, it will sell bonds to buy stocks. It will do the same in reverse if the market soars. All while keeping a very low expense ratio and needing no action on your part.

Answer (score -1):

You could accomplish this with any ETF and a limit order. Just decide what price indicates the stock market has crashed and set the limit order to buy at that price or better.

Comment: Buy what exactly?

Comment: @etf_question The ETF.

Comment: Not really what is asked here. OP wants to know if a hybrid active/passive fund exists, one they would ideally be invested in and have qualities of a passive index fund during an economy boom but switch to active management to weather recessions/market crashes.